# Storing & running Intellij project on the cloud

Tags: git, intellij-idea, cloud

I'm trying to store my Project files for this term in my CMPT class on the cloud (ownCloud) so that any changes I make at home or at campus are saved to the same place. I have found it was simple enough to save the project there, but when trying to compile & test at campus, the project asks for an output location. Can someone help me understand what I need to watch out for when storing my projects on the cloud? For example, when I compile files, do I have to tell the IDE where to run them from?

On a final note, I also run GIT as the version control for my projects. Do I need to separately import the file location, or does it do it automatically?

I know this is a bit of a naive, but I'm trying hard this term to work with cloud storage and version control.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Arent the two functions (cloud and version control) overlapping? Wouldnt it be better to use distributed version control (like github) and no cloud?

Comment: @vikingsteve the version control is for the code in the project, and the project on the cloud is meant so I can access it while at home/campus. It was an issue for me previous term.

Comment: Why dont you install intellij locally at campus, and then locally at home? It seems unecessary to have the project in the cloud. You can sync the project code via github